# React Native. Клик по кнопке при открытой клавиатуре

Tags: android, reactjs, ios, react-native, expo

Всем привет!

Проблема такая:

При открытой клавиатуре, если нажать на кнопку Continue, то кнопка не срабатывает. Вместо этого срабатывает закрытие клавиатуры. И только потом можно уже нажимать на кнопку.
Как сделать так, чтобы клик по кнопке работал при открытой клаве?

Проверял, что при клике при открытой клаве не срабатывает даже onPress на любом элементе

```
return (
        <>
            <GoBack />
            <ErrorModal error={error} resetError={setError} />
            <ScrollView>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
                <View >
                    <View>
                        <IconsMap.LogoIconGradient />
                    </View>
                    <Text>
                        {lang.create_acc}
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                        {lang.create_acc_desc}
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput                  
                        value={store.phone}
                        placeholder={lang.enter_phone_number}
                        placeholderTextColor={color.phonePlaceholder}
                        onChangeText={(phone) => (store.phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9+]/g, ''))}
                        onSubmitEditing={onContinue}
                        keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                        textContentType={'telephoneNumber'} 
                    />
                    <XButton.Continue  onClick={onContinue} disabled={loader} loader={loader}/>
                    
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </ScrollView>
        </>
    )
```

Comment: Может у вас клавиатура перекрывает все элементы? Создает подложку прозрачную и клик срабатывает на ней.

Comment: Я могу скроллить с показанной клавиатурой, так что не думаю, но спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена! Дело было в ScrollView. Нужно добавить keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
 <SOME CODE/>
</ScrollView>
```